# Why doesnt creating a sym link from python to python 3 work?

Tags: python, mac, terminal, symlink

My goal is to make sure that `python` refers to `python3` in my mac terminal. What i have tried so far are the following two attempts

#### 1. Adding an alias in .zshrc

```
alias python=python3
```

after re sourcing my `.zshrc` file this allowed me to type `python --version` and get python3.

This does not work for scripts as they specify `#!/usr/bin/env python` and completely ignore my aliases.

#### 2. Adding a symlink from `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`

This is when it gets weird. Here are the output of a few commands

`python --version` -> `python 2.7`

`which python` -> `python /usr/local/bin/python`

`/usr/local/bin/python --version` -> `python 2.7`

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` -> `/usr/local/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python3`

`/usr/bin/python3 --version` -> `python 3.8`

What is going wrong here? Why is the symlink apparently correct but the wrong version of python is still showing when using it?

[I found a similar question on an old apple](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432233/why-does-the-shell-run-the-incorrect-python) but the answer doesn't really address the weirdness of the symlink, nor doesnt it solve the problem.

I'd really like to understand why this is happening AND find a solutionn or a proper way to get my main python version to be python 3.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it too impractical to just update your scripts to point to the version you want? For example, change `#!/usr/bin/env python` to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`? Unless you’re sure of everything that makes use of a particular version, changing it by completely disallowing it via soft links or something could have unintended consequences.

Comment: I can do that, and that is what i ended up doing. I am still curious about the weirdness with symlinks tho. any ideas ?

Comment: Run `hash python` in case your shell cached that it was in /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 1):

check current python version:
`$ python --version`: output `Python 2.*` OR `Command 'python' not found`

check current python3 version:
`$ python3 --version`: output `Python 3.*`

Check where python3 is located:
`$ which python3`: output `/usr/bin/python3`

**Create your sym link here**:
`$ sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`
where /usr/bin/python is the new executable

exit terminal + reopen

Now check your `python` executable is actually running python3

`$ python --version`: output `Python 3.*`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, the whole problem is that creating a link is NOT allowed: ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted